# В чём заключается разница TLB и MMU?

Tags: архитектура, paging

Нужно описать как переводится **логический адрес** в **физический**.
+ не очень понимаю что происходит при TLB miss, как себя ведёт при этом TBL и MMU (как они связаны, когда происходит page fault)

Благодарю за ответы

Comment: Так всё-таки вас интересует разница между TLB (кэш переводов адресов) и MMU (девайс, который этим занимается) или то, что в вопросе написано?

Comment: И то и другое было бы вполне не лишним

Comment: Тогда лучше создайте два отдельных вопроса и в каждом опишите своё понимание и что вы уже читали на эту тему.

Comment: По хорошему TLB это часть MMU. При page fault нет особого смысла смотреть что в это время делает MMU. Оно попыталось найти адрес в TLB, получило miss, попыталось получить адрес из таблицы страниц (или каталога), обнаружило бит не присутствия, возбудило page fault. Все, на этом его роль окончена. Дальше уже ОС обеспечивает присутствие страницы. Когда обеспечит - вернет управление прерванной операции, та полезет в память, MMU увидит что страница есть, загрузит адреса в TLB и по информации из него отдаст команды на шину